# Optaplanner ConstraintFactory - from seems to return uninitialized entities

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am attempting to solve a simple proof of concept problem using Optaplanner, and I am running into an inconsistency. The documentation (and other SO questions) seems to indicate that `ConstraintFactory.from()` should only return initialized planning entities. [(like here)](https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.11.1.Final/optaplanner-javadoc/org/optaplanner/core/api/score/stream/ConstraintFactory.html#from(java.lang.Class))

I have the following planning entity (relevant code only):

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Enrollment {

    @PlanningId
    private UUID id;

    private Student student;
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "possibleLessons", nullable = true)
    private Lesson lesson;

    // No-arg constructor required for OptaPlanner
    public Enrollment() {
    }

    public Enrollment(UUID id, Student student) {
        this.id = id;
        this.student = student;
    }

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public Lesson getLesson() {
        return lesson;
    }
}
```

and tried to introduce the following constraint:

```
    private Constraint studentsLikePreferredSubjects(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory
                .from(Enrollment.class)
                .filter(enrollment -> enrollment.getStudent().getPreferredSubjects().contains(enrollment.getLesson().getSubject()))
                .reward("Student likes subject bonus", HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT);
    }
```

This code does NOT work, since I get a nullpointerexception on `getLesson`: `Cannot invoke "Lesson.getSubject()" because the return value of "Enrollment.getLesson()" is null`

However, adding a filter to filter out null-lessons DOES work:

```
    private Constraint studentsLikePreferredSubjects(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory
                .from(Enrollment.class)
                .filter(enrollment -> enrollment.getLesson() != null)
                .filter(enrollment -> enrollment.getStudent().getPreferredSubjects().contains(enrollment.getLesson().getSubject()))
                .reward("Student likes subject bonus", HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT);
    }
```

Of course I could just use this code, but I don't understand why it is necessary: I would expect no `Enrollment`s with `null` `Lesson`s to be contained in the stream, since I am using `from` (and not `fromUnfiltered`). Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConstraintFactory.from()` only returns initialized planning entities, unless `nullable = true` (by default, nullable is false, so `from()` filters).

In your code, `nullable = true` (you're doing overconstrained planning), so `from()` returns all entities.

Comment: This behavior is a bit surprising I guess. If we ever end up branching 9.0, we might want to [change this behavior](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2295).

Comment: Technically, there is a difference between "null" and "uninitialized". `from()` will skip the entities which are uninitialized, in other words those that would result in a negative init score. `nullable` variables can be `null` even without a negative init score (after construction heuristics). "null" does not mean "uninitialized".

Comment: In theory there is a difference. In practice: For first time planning yes. For replanning (for example in continuous planning for employee rostering), things get murky. I am not sure if we want to start relying on that behavior, some to discuss :)

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet Thanks! Two quick points. First, you say "unless nullable = true (which it is by default)", but isn't false the default? See https://docs.optaplanner.org/8.11.1.Final/optaplanner-javadoc/org/optaplanner/core/api/domain/variable/PlanningVariable.html#nullable()

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet Also, to me your answer contradicts the current docs, specifically 4.3.4.2 Nullable planning variable which I based my original code on. This says "Constraint Streams filter out planning entities with a null planning variable by default. Use fromUnfiltered() to avoid such unwanted behaviour." directly after introducing nullable = true. This to me implies `from()` should also filter when nullable is true.
Of course I believe your answer here is correct, but then maybe the docs should be clarified on this point.

Comment: This is good feedback. Clearly the docs can improve - we'll look into it. (and yes, I meant "by default it's null" - fixing my answer).

Comment: We will be looking into it in https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2535.